# How to get the fitted values of the underlying model run in CADFtest in R?

Tags: r, regression, lm, usage-statistics

I'm using the package `CADFtest` in `R`, and I've some issues retrieving the fitted values of the underlying regression model on which Hansen's ADF test is implemented. Here is an example from the help page:

```
install.packages("CADFtest")
require(CADFtest)    
data(npext, package="urca")
npext$unemrate <- exp(npext$unemploy)      # compute unemployment rate
L <- ts(npext, start=1860)                 # time series of levels
D <- diff(L)                               # time series of diffs
S <- window(ts.intersect(L,D), start=1909) # select same sample as Hansen's
CADFt <- CADFtest(L.gnpperca~D.unemrate, data=S, max.lag.y=3,
  kernel="Parzen", prewhite=FALSE)
```

Running `CADFt` returns:

```
> CADFt
    CADF test

data:  L.gnpperca ~ D.unemrate
CADF(3,0,0) = -3.413, rho2 = 0.063515, p-value = 0.001729
alternative hypothesis: true delta is less than 0
sample estimates:
      delta 
-0.08720302
```

Which is a model with 3 lagged dependent variables. I'd like to extract the fitted values of this model. So I run

```
> CADFt$est.model$fitted.values
Time Series:
Start = 5 
End = 80 
Frequency = 1 
 [1]  0.0005662303 -0.0733646249 -0.0126602690  0.0697401891  0.0143332199  0.0857608955 -0.0086049916 -0.0558618079 -0.1410753680  0.1223887323  0.0880077675 -0.0201279048  0.0552825504  0.0245985124 -0.0157488507
[16] -0.0089621034  0.0251877185 -0.1101706369 -0.1229540835 -0.1562289335  0.0118467889  0.0942232745  0.0830000974  0.1186187635  0.0906191863 -0.0591099094  0.0709325962  0.0693442793  0.1384204645  0.1287152465
[31]  0.0814823568  0.0201579212 -0.0101185970 -0.0409656385  0.0056581976 -0.0016591031 -0.0236250458  0.0387140051  0.0515742055  0.0306409595  0.0187764792 -0.0455932936  0.0433190872  0.0115143178  0.0218779596
[46] -0.0395455081  0.0481404678  0.0139747978  0.0043631927  0.0447783346  0.0148757356  0.0371630123  0.0325870648  0.0340326292  0.0171292682  0.0220503307  0.0121438056 -0.0129218323 -0.0055278586  0.0180975211
[61]  0.0320353864  0.0026341644 -0.0411863408  0.0312942735  0.0272606802  0.0450317222  0.0238727288 -0.0078678757  0.0073786290 -0.0282459788  0.0291874998  0.0613006522  0.0330602986  0.0320649803  0.0375408342
[76]  0.0360327436
```

However, the initial dependent variable `L.gnpperca` has observations that are very different:

```
> S[,8]
Time Series:
Start = 1909 
End = 1988 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 7.163172 7.170120 7.179308 7.219642 7.208600 7.144407 7.121252 7.183112 7.177019 7.293698 7.244942 7.181592 7.070724 7.204149 7.301148 7.279319 7.345365 7.388946 7.374002 7.367709 7.421177 7.306531 7.218177
[24] 7.050989 7.026427 7.106606 7.193686 7.317212 7.362645 7.302496 7.376508 7.450080 7.589336 7.699842 7.809947 7.867489 7.839132 7.701200 7.673223 7.699842 7.683404 7.758761 7.818028 7.830823 7.858254 7.826443
[47] 7.882315 7.883069 7.879291 7.851272 7.896553 7.900637 7.903596 7.951911 7.976595 8.015988 8.064951 8.116417 8.131236 8.166784 8.182280 8.165079 8.178548 8.216426 8.257559 8.243015 8.220508 8.258717 8.294266
[70] 8.335247 8.348691 8.335095 8.343870 8.307756 8.333102 8.389362 8.412748 8.430085 8.456477 8.490848
```

I wonder whether the fitted value refers to the first-differenced model. How to obtain the actual fitted values? Thank you.